# Solution to linear program when $Ax\leq 0$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I want to solve the linear program:
$max. c^T  x $ $\\$subject to $Ax \leq 0 \\
            x\geq 0 $

If I introduce slack variables $s_i$, then I can rewrite it as
$ min. -c^T x \\ 
s.t.  A'y=0 \\ y\geq 0 ,  y= (x_1,..,x_n, s_1, ...,s_n)^T , A'= [A\space I_n] $

and the dual problem becomes $max  -0^Tv \\ s.t. A'^Tv-\lambda +c =0 \\ \lambda \geq0$

I'm not sure if this is correct so far and also not sure how I can proceed to find a solution.  The $0$ also makes this surprising for me since the value stays at $0$, how exactly will it maximise?

Comment: The constraint at the dual is no constraint. And what do you mean by $A^{'T}$?

Comment: My bad, I edited to make it a constraint equation. $A'^T$ is the transpose of $A'$. The dual constraint is something I was taught in class.